# Does every page rendering load remote libraries?

Tags: javascript, cdn

As per below code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Intro</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
     <body>
     </body>
</html>
```

Does each page rendering load the remote library from CDN?

Answer (score 4):

No, browsers normally cache the external files after they loaded the files once. Unless user manually clears the browser's cache, or the file on the server changes (depending on the web server that serves the content, it is not under browser's control) they don't download the file again.

CDNs are supposed to be distributed and deliver those static files to the clients as fast as possible. They usually support all sorts of compressing to speed up this delivery.

You can read more about CDN [here](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/CDN.html) or you can search it yourself on [google](https://www.google.com/?q=what%20is%20cdn).

Comment: file on the server changes? I did not get you. Why does jQuery library file sit in webserver, unless it is a local jQuery file?

Comment: @overexchange Generally, the file on the server could change. For jQuery it might not be the case, even if you serve it locally, it shouldn't change, so browser would not download it again.

Answer (score 3):

No only the first time. After being loaded the first time it is cached in the browser.